# VBA error when triggering "change" event on IE input field

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use VBA to access an internal web page using Internet Explorer, open a search window, enter search parameters and run the search. My code will click all of the buttons, find all of the text boxes and enter the parameters. But, it does not recognize any of the parameters entered using ".value" (i.e., objElement.value = "1234567"). I have written the code based on what I have read in this forum and a number of others but, obviously, I'm still missing something. When it tries to trigger the "change" event, I receive either an Error 438 - Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method, or an Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument. The error depends on whether I use dispatchEvent or FireEvent and whether I use the collection or the element within the collection as the object. My guess is the problem lies with my declarations but, I tried a few different ones, and still get the errors.

Unfortunately, this is accessing an internal site so you won't be able to run the code. I'm hoping someone can just take a look and point me in the right direction.

```
Dim EPA As String
Dim EPANumb As Integer
Dim EPAList() As String
Dim PrjCnt As Long
Dim PrjList As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim URL As String
Dim HWNDSrc As Long
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim objElement As Object

Dim objEvent As Object
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLtags As IHTMLElementCollection


'Pull list of project numbers and enter into array
fn = ThisWorkbook.Name
EPANumb = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Instructions").Range("B:B"))
EPANumb = EPANumb - 2
ReDim EPAList(EPANumb)
For PrjCnt = 0 To EPANumb
    If EPANumb > 0 Then
        EPAList(PrjCnt) = "'" & Worksheets("Instructions").Cells((PrjCnt + 2), 2).Value & "'"
    Else
        EPAList(PrjCnt) = Worksheets("Instructions").Cells((PrjCnt + 2), 2).Value
    End If
Next

PrjList = Join(EPAList, ",")

'Open IE and navigate to URL
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Visible = True 'only if you want to see what is happening
URL = "http://anysite/SnakeEyes/grid.html"
IE.navigate URL
'need If statement in case user needs to do sign on.

' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

'Webpage Loaded
Application.StatusBar = URL & " loaded"
Set oHtml = IE.document

'HWNDScr = IE.HWND
'SetForegroundWindow HWNDScr

'Open search box and reset search parameters
oHtml.getElementById("search_grid_c_top").Click
'IE.Document.getElementById("fbox_grid_c_reset").Click
Set objEvent = oHtml.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
objEvent.initEvent "change", True, False ' **** NEW ****

Set HTMLtags = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("select")
For i = 0 To HTMLtags.Length - 1
    If HTMLtags(i).className = "selectopts" Then
        If EPANumb > 0 Then
            HTMLtags(i).Value = "in"
        Else
            HTMLtags(i).Value = "eq"
        End If
'        HTMLtags.dispatchEvent objEvent ' **** NEW ****
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Set objEvent = oHtml.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
objEvent.initEvent "change", True, False ' **** NEW ****

Set HTMLtags = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("input")
For i = 1 To HTMLtags.Length - 1
    If HTMLtags(i).ID > "jqg" And HTMLtags(i).ID < "jqh" Then
        HTMLtags(i).Focus
        HTMLtags(i).Value = PrjList
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

HTMLtags(i).dispatchEvent objEvent ' **** NEW ****
'HTMLtags(i).FireEvent objEvent ' **** NEW **** DispatchEvent gives an error 438.
'FireEvent gives an error 5 if using the (i); error 438 without it.
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldaY2.png)

Comment: What is the html element you want to operate? Do you want to change option in `<select>` tag? Please also provide the html sample. You could provide the screenshot of the html elements of the page or a simple sample of the html element you want to operate. So that we can have a better understanding of the issue and see how to help.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the HTML code. The link is above. There are no events associated with the drop down box, but there is a "change" event associated with the input box. I'm hoping the change event trigger the update for both.

Answer (score 0):

Will the "change" event trigger the update for both without VBA in IE? If the "change" event is only associated with the input box and will not trigger update for dropdown list without VBA, then I think it won't work with VBA either. Besides, what the "change" event is like?

I make a demo like below and it seems that the "change" event can be triggered well, you could try to check it.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="operators">
                    <select class="selectopts">
                        <option value="eq">equal</option>
                        <option value="in">is in</option>
                        <option value="ni">is not in</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    <input class="input-elm" id="jqg1" role="textbox" type="text" size="10" value="'1006191'"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        var select = document.getElementsByClassName('selectopts')(0);
        var input = document.getElementById('jqg1');

        input.addEventListener('change', updateValue);

        function updateValue() {
            select.value = "in";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**VBA code:**

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "http://somewebsite"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = ieA.Document
    Set Search = doc.getElementByID("jqg1")
    Search.Value = "VBA"

    Dim event_onChange As Object
    Set event_onChange = ieA.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False
    Search.dispatchEvent event_onChange

    'ieA.Quit
    'Set ieA = Nothing
End Sub
```